# post data JSON webservice

Tags: iphone, json

i want to post data on a server and i am using jSON webservice.
i know how to get data from server using Json but don't know abt posting data
can any one help me plz....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a `NSURLConnection` set the content type to `text/json` and `POST` it as a string or you can use `ASIHTTPRequest` for easier connection management.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:[jsonString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] forKey:@"data"];

[request startAsynchronous];
```